# d3 enumerating from the middle of a list?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a rather mysterious issue with a d3 chart I'm working on.

Here is the code for two pieces of data-driven charting that I am working on. The first populates the bars on a bar chart while the second populates the labels:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(nyb.features)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr({
                "fill": "steelblue",
                "width": bar_width,
                "height": function(d) { return 250 - y(d.properties.distance) - 5; },
                "x": function(d, i) { return ((bar_width + 1) * i) + 55; },
                "y": function(d) { return y(d.properties.distance); }
            });

    svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(nyb.features)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr({
                "fill": "red",
                "x": function(d, i) { console.log(i); return ((bar_width + 1) * i) + 55; },
                "y": function(d) { return y(d.properties.distance); }
            })
            .text("Hello World!");
```

I expect this to generate a set of bars and a set of textual labels for those bars.

For some reason this is my output instead:

[image]

Checking the console, this seems to be caused by d3 starting to enumerate through the data only in the middle:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: The full visualization code is [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/mysite/blob/master/templates/visualizations/longest-streets.html). The data being used is [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/mysite/blob/master/static/post_assets/nyc-addresses/streets.geojson).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tempted to close this as a duplicate since I just answered a similar question yesterday, but once more for posterity...*

Don't use `svg.selectAll("text")` and `svg.selectAll("rect")`, you are saying give me all the `text` in this svg and are inadvertently selecting elements you don't want to.  Hence you have a smaller enter selection, somethings already exist.

Better way to do it is:

```
svg.selectAll(".myUniqueClass")
  .data(nyb.features)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "myUniqueClass")
  ...
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's a quite subtle but important error. Well, I won't make it again! Thank you!

Comment: Hey, @Mark, why don't you post a question about this recurrent problem, give it yourself a very detailed answer explaining d3 selections, accept it (off course), and use this question to "mark as duplicate" next time someone asks the same thing?